# list[i] returning null even though the list is populated

Tags: c#, list, collections

**UPDATE:** Suddenly works as expected for no particular reason. VS being weird I guess.

See image below. ubBenefitMatches has 1 item populated as seen in the watch window but when I try to set the benefit string to that value, it returns null. I've tried a bunch of variations, foreach loops etc, not that it should matter.

Does anyone have an explanation as to what logic is occurring here?

[image]

Same thing with .ElementAt
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Checked in vs2012 and vs2010 - same issue.

Comment: it is possible for an element in a collection to be null.

Comment: Actually, `ubBenefitMatches[i].ToString()` is `null`. Is your `ToString` method overriden, perhaps? Unless `ubBenefitMatches` is simply `string[]`?

Comment: @user1666620 Yeah, it is, but as the screenshot shows the first element of the list isn't.

Comment: @Groo I just added the .ToString to try to force the issue, no avail though. Not overridden either

Comment: @Kiearn: so line `164` doesn't throw, but `benefit` is null afterwards?

Comment: ubBenefit is a `List<string>` ?

Comment: @Groo correct, benefit comes out as null, even though ubBenefitMatches has a value in position 0.

Comment: @derpirscher Correct, ubBenefit is List<string>

Comment: So, placing `Debug.Assert(null != ubBenefitMatches[0])` before the loop works? Are you sure you are looking at the correct source code, and the project has been properly built?

Comment: @Groo yes sir. No error thrown

Comment: this might be stupid, but what happens if you clean and rebuild the solution or restart VS?

Comment: Where is your breakpoint in the screenshot? If `ubBenefitMatches[i]` is `null`, there must be a `NullReferenceException` on line 164 (like @Groo said)

Comment: @user1666620 tried, no change

Comment: are you debugging by launching the application from VS, or are you attached to a running process?

Comment: @derpirscher the breakpoint was set on line 164, I advanced one line and removed the breakpoint for a clearer image

Comment: @KieranQuinn If `ubBenefitMatches[i]` is really null, you cannot reach line 165 without an exception thrown.

Comment: @derpirscher `ubBenefitMatches[i]` isn't null. It contains `"Hospital_Inpatient_Stay"` as shown in the Watch panel.

Comment: @derpirscher I understand. It obviously is not null as you can see in the watch, but when I try to get that value in position [0], it returns null

Comment: I would extract this piece of code into a new test console app, and run it from there. The reason for this is either 1) The source file is not in match with the executable, 2) Visual Studio is acting funny at this moment and needs to be restarted, or 3) You have found a bug in VS2015/Roslyn.

Comment: @KieranQuinn The wierd thing is that `ubBenefitMatches[0]` is not null. `ToString()` is returning null which is completely different. If `ubBenefitMatches[0]` were null you'd be getting a `NullReferenceException` at 164.

Comment: Have you tried `ubBenefitMatches.ElementAt(i)`? This whole thing seems very strange.

Comment: @derpirscher Just tried, same. Very strange indeed.

Comment: And what values gest added to `matches`?

Comment: @DovydasSopa nothing gets added. matches is null

Comment: Can you add a real snippet of code and a demo on .NETFiddle?

Comment: @Kieran Quinn Then how you step into line `167`?

Comment: @DovydasSopa its obviously picking up a match for 'Null' in bookmarkItems